# Android Settings and popup menu for settings

Tags: android

I'm working on settings within my app. However when i try to call the setting i get the following error. 
i'm using sliding menu and ABS. it would seem from the following error that it is interfering with my settings being called properly. Can anyone tell from this log what is causing it to crash?

```
05-07 15:22:36.792: W/dalvikvm(5650): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
05-07 15:22:36.822: E/AndroidRuntime(5650): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-07 15:22:36.822: E/AndroidRuntime(5650): java.lang.NullPointerException
05-07 15:22:36.822: E/AndroidRuntime(5650):     at com.projectcaruso.naturalfamilyplaning.FragmentChange.showUserSettings(FragmentChange.java:130)
05-07 15:22:36.822: E/AndroidRuntime(5650):     at com.projectcaruso.naturalfamilyplaning.FragmentChange.onOptionsItemSelected(FragmentChange.java:100)
05-07 15:22:36.822: E/AndroidRuntime(5650):     at android.support.v4.app.Watson.onMenuItemSelected(Watson.java:118)
05-07 15:22:36.822: E/AndroidRuntime(5650):     at com.actionbarsherlock.ActionBarSherlock.callbackOptionsItemSelected(ActionBarSherlock.java:603)
05-07 15:22:36.822: E/AndroidRuntime(5650):     at com.actionbarsherlock.internal.ActionBarSherlockNative.dispatchOptionsItemSelected(ActionBarSherlockNative.java:93)
05-07 15:22:36.822: E/AndroidRuntime(5650):     at com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragmentActivity.onMenuItemSelected(SherlockFragmentActivity.java:205)
05-07 15:22:36.822: E/AndroidRuntime(5650):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.onMenuItemSelected(PhoneWindow.java:980)
05-07 15:22:36.822: E/AndroidRuntime(5650):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:735)
05-07 15:22:36.822: E/AndroidRuntime(5650):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:149)
05-07 15:22:36.822: E/AndroidRuntime(5650):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:874)
05-07 15:22:36.822: E/AndroidRuntime(5650):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.ListMenuPresenter.onItemClick(ListMenuPresenter.java:166)
05-07 15:22:36.822: E/AndroidRuntime(5650):     at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:298)
05-07 15:22:36.822: E/AndroidRuntime(5650):     at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1100)
05-07 15:22:36.822: E/AndroidRuntime(5650):     at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2749)
05-07 15:22:36.822: E/AndroidRuntime(5650):     at android.widget.AbsListView$1.run(AbsListView.java:3423)
05-07 15:22:36.822: E/AndroidRuntime(5650):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
05-07 15:22:36.822: E/AndroidRuntime(5650):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
05-07 15:22:36.822: E/AndroidRuntime(5650):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-07 15:22:36.822: E/AndroidRuntime(5650):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
05-07 15:22:36.822: E/AndroidRuntime(5650):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-07 15:22:36.822: E/AndroidRuntime(5650):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-07 15:22:36.822: E/AndroidRuntime(5650):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
05-07 15:22:36.822: E/AndroidRuntime(5650):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
05-07 15:22:36.822: E/AndroidRuntime(5650):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Here's my java:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.projectcaruso:
        Util.goToGitHub(this);
        return true;
    case R.id.about:
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        .setTitle(R.string.about)
        .setMessage(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.about_msg)))
        .show();
        break;
    case R.id.licenses:
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        .setTitle(R.string.licenses)
        .setMessage(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.license_detail)))
        .show();
        break;
    case R.id.contact:
        final Intent email = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
        String uriText = "mailto:jfeinstein10@gmail.com" +
                "?subject=" + URLEncoder.encode("SlidingMenu Demos Feedback"); 
        email.setData(Uri.parse(uriText));
        try {
            startActivity(email);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(this, R.string.no_email, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        break;
    case R.id.settings:
        showUserSettings();
        break;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getSupportMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.settings, menu);
    return true;
}


private void showUserSettings() {
    SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

    builder.append("\n Username: "
            + sharedPrefs.getString("prefUsername", "NULL"));

    builder.append("\n Send report:"
            + sharedPrefs.getBoolean("prefSendReport", false));

    builder.append("\n Sync Frequency: "
            + sharedPrefs.getString("prefSyncFrequency", "NULL"));

    TextView settingsTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textUserSettings);

    settingsTextView.setText(builder.toString());
}
```

EDIT XML:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
        <item 
            android:id="@+id/projectcaruso" 
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_github"
            android:showAsAction="always" 
            android:title="@string/projectcaruso_label" 
            android:titleCondensed="@string/projectcaruso" 
            android:visible="true">
        </item>
        <item 
            android:id="@+id/about" 
            android:title="@string/about" 
            android:showAsAction="never" 
            android:orderInCategory="1">
        </item>
        <item 
            android:id="@+id/licenses" 
            android:title="@string/licenses" 
            android:showAsAction="never" 
            android:orderInCategory="2">
        </item>
        <item 
            android:id="@+id/contact" 
            android:title="@string/contact" 
            android:orderInCategory="3" 
            android:showAsAction="never">
        </item>
            <item 
            android:id="@+id/settings" 
            android:title="@string/settings" 
            android:orderInCategory="3" 
            android:showAsAction="never">
        </item>
    </menu>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `settingsTextView`  is `null`

Try to refer `TextView` like this

```
TextView settingsTextView = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.textUserSettings);
```